# Navigation Drawer not showing at all (android)

Tags: android, layout, navigation, navigation-drawer, overlapping

I followed a fairly simple guide as to add a navigation drawer, but the drawer isn't there when running the app, and the layouts for the main screen and the drawer are both being displayed in the main avtivity, overlapping. ://

Any ideas?

EDIT: misspelled an attribute... Wrote `android:gravity`, instead of `android:layout_gravity` *feeling stupid :P*

Here's the xml layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.kapres.test2.MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/main_screen"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test2"
            android:textSize="38dp"
            android:paddingTop="32dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_layout"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left|start">

    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's the java code:

```
package com.kapres.test2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> mainMenuList = new ArrayList<String>();

        mainMenuList.add("item1");
        mainMenuList.add("item2");
        mainMenuList.add("item3");
        mainMenuList.add("item4");
        mainMenuList.add("item5");

        ArrayAdapter mainMenuAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mainMenuList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_menu_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(mainMenuAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create another project, choose a Navigation drawer template and try to see what you did differently. Just an idea.

Comment: You should consider using the drawer as the built-in way android provides (with a menu file), if so I'll post an answer with an example

Comment: I see, I got it working though. What are the benefits of using the navigation drawer template? I have taken a quick look at it, but it seems like kind of an overkill for my application :p I'm still new to this (one week), and I'm really only trying to make something simple for my first self-written app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the layout for fully working drawer. Pay attention to android:layout_gravity="start" attribute. If you remove that line, the drawer would always be opened. This is useful for editing.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/background">

</LinearLayout>
```

DrawerActivity:

```
// 1. Set content view
    setContentView(R.layout.app_drawer);
    // 2. Set drawer layout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Update user data end etc.
            loadUserDataOntoDrawer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

        }
    });
    mDrawerContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_content);

    // Initialize your data adapter
    mMenuDataAdapter = new MenuDataAdapter(MenuHolder.getInstance().getMenuItemList());
    // Find recyclerview
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    // Define layout manager
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    // Set adapter
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMenuDataAdapter);
    // Set animator
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInUpAnimator(new OvershootInterpolator(1f)));
```

Comment: Thanks, I had misspelled the gravity attribute, forgot "layout_".

Answer (score 0):

BoilerPlate method to show your drawer however in your Activity you are not calling the drawer at all

```
  private NavigationView navigationView;
  private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
```

and then

```
  private void setupDrawerLayout() {
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), menuItem.getItemId()
                + menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, sorry guys, found the problem. Just a stupid typo. I wrote "android:gravity(...)" insted of "android:layout_gravity(...)" Realised when I compared Gregorys code with my ovn. Thanks!